# MS Teams Custom App Personal Tab external website SSL(https) question

Tags: microsoft-teams

When registering MS TEAMS custom app, I am trying to connect an external site to my personal tab.
If it is not an SSL (https) site that has been authenticated when connecting, does it not connect normally when clicking after registering the MS Teams app?

Register personal tab after applying ssl in node.js (no authentication)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few important prerequisites for a Tab app in Microsoft Teams. Included in these are that the app must be running on an httpS endpoint, and that it must reference the Teams JS library. It sounds like your app is not doing either of those.

Please see here for more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements